# Empty Array returned when using array.sort() with return or print in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, sorting, printing, return

```
print(array.sort())
return array.sort()
```

> print or return an empty array = `[]`

while if I do this

```
array.sort()
print(array)
  OR
array.sort()
return array
```

> Gives me a sorted array = `[1, 4, 9, 10]`

Why is it like this I tried understanding the working of the inbuilt code for sorting but couldn't understand? Is it a memory problem or something else?

Comment: It's because `sort()` acts on the array itself and doesn't return the sorted array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sort` sorts the array and returns `None`. For example:

```
>> a1 = [1, 9, 10, 4]    
>> a1.sort()
>> print(a1)
[1, 4, 9, 10]
```

On the other hand, `sorted` returns a sorted copy of the original array, but the original array remains unsorted.

```
>> a2 = [1, 9, 10, 4]    
>> print(sorted(a2))
[1, 9, 10, 4] 
>> print(a2)
[1, 4, 9, 10]
```